# Why is the return value of the ace editor's getScrollTop function different from the value of the scrollTop property?

Tags: ace-editor

[image]

I just test in browser console and find that the two values are different, and I use `editor.renderer.scrollToY` to change the scrollTop vlaue.

```js
const targetY = editor.renderer.lineHeight * (editor.getCursorPositionScreen().row - 2);
editor.renderer.scrollToY(targetY);
editor.clearSelection();
```

Does anyone encounter the same problem.